# How do you retrieve ONLY the select property from your iOS contacts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts

we're having an issue where incorrect selections are being returned from the contacts database on some devices. Is there a way to modify the below code to only return the selected item from a persons contact information? In this case we want the exact selected email address from a persons contact to be returned.

Thanks in advance for the help! Heres the code...

```
-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController     *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:     (ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{

    NSMutableDictionary *contactInfoDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                            initWithObjects:@[@"", @"", @""]
                                            forKeys:@[@"first_name", @"last_name",     @"email"]];

    // Use a general Core Foundation object.
    CFTypeRef generalCFObject = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

    // Get the first name.
    if (generalCFObject) {
        [contactInfoDict setObject:(__bridge NSString *)generalCFObject     forKey:@"first_name"];
        CFRelease(generalCFObject);
    }

    // Get the last name.
    generalCFObject = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    if (generalCFObject) {
        [contactInfoDict setObject:(__bridge NSString *)generalCFObject     forKey:@"last_name"];
        CFRelease(generalCFObject);
    }

    // Load selected email addre'
    if (property == kABPersonEmailProperty) {
        ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
        CFIndex ix = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(emails, identifier);
        CFStringRef email = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, ix);

        emailAccount = (__bridge NSString *)(email);
        [contactInfoDict setObject:emailAccount forKey:@"email"];

        if (email) CFRelease(email);
        if (emails) CFRelease(emails);
    }

    // init array
    if (_arrContactsData == nil) {
        _arrContactsData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    // Send contact to server
    [self sendContact:contactInfoDict];

    // Set data for contacts
    [_arrContactsData addObject:contactInfoDict];

    // Reload the table view data.
    [self.myTable reloadData];

    // Dismiss the address book view controller.
    [_addressBookController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: The code you posted looks right. Are you saying that under some cases, the value of `email` is the not the selected email address?

Comment: Yes exactly. On certain devices the returned email address is not the address the user selected. @rmaddy

Comment: Agreed. Are you able to consistently reproduce this (and if so, how)? Also, have you logged these three properties here and made sure that the problem is truly in this routine and not, for example, in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, or something else accidentally mutating this object after the information is retrieved from the address book?

Comment: That having been said, it might be safer to make an immutable copy of `contactInfoDict` before using it in other methods or in the array (because you have no assurances that some other method couldn't mutate this object). And I might make `emailAccount` a local variable, as it makes me nervous to be changing some random ivar, though that's unlikely to be related to the problem at hand. But other than those two observations, I don't see anything terribly worrying here.

Comment: So, is there a way to make sure the exact property tapped on by a user gets returned? Right now it seems that a user can tap 1 email address but a different email address gets returned. Why would this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.

Are the users experiencing the problem using iOS 8, by any chance? I discovered a bug in iOS 8 beta 6. If you:

1. Create a contact with email addresses:

   [image: create contact]
2. Edit the contact, adding an email address and deleting one of the other email addresses:

   [image: edit contact]

   (Note, don't just edit one of the email addresses, but rather add a new email address and remove and old one.)
3. In iOS 7, if you iterate through the email addresses, you will see:

   ```
   {
       identifier = 1;
       index = 0;
       label = "_$!<Work>!$_";
       value = "work@gmail.com";
   },
   {
       identifier = 2;
       index = 1;
       label = "_$!<Other>!$_";
       value = "other@gmail.com";
   }
   ```

   This is correct. (When the contact was first created, the identifiers were `0` and `1`, when I add the "other" email address, that gets an identifier of `2`; when I delete the "home" email address, the email address with the identifier of `0` is deleted, but the other identifiers are correctly unaltered.) Thus, if you tap on the "work" email address, `shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson` will return an `ABMultiValueIdentifier` of `1`, which translates to a `CFIndex` of `0`, which will correctly return the "work" email address.

   In iOS 8 Beta 6, however, the `ABMultiValueRef` is incorrectly represented as:

   ```
   {
       identifier = 0;
       index = 0;
       label = "_$!<Work>!$_";
       value = "work@gmail.com";
   },
   {
       identifier = 1;
       index = 1;
       label = "_$!<Other>!$_";
       value = "other@gmail.com";
   }
   ```

   These identifiers are incorrect. Worse, if you tap on the "work" email address, `didSelectPerson` (which replaces the deprecated `shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson`) will return a `ABMultiValueIdentifier` of `1` (which is what it should have been ... it looks like this delegate method returns the appropriate `identifier`, but that the `ABRecordRef` for this edited record has the wrong identifiers ... not sure how they did that!), which translates to a `CFIndex` of `1`, which will correctly return the "other" email address (!).

   Worse, if you tapped on the "other" email address, `didSelectPerson` will return a `ABMultiValueIdentifier` of `2` (which is what it should have been), but if you try to retrieve the `CFIndex`, you'll get `-1` (because no such `ABMultiValueIdentifier` exists) and because the app doesn't check for this, any attempt to use `ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex` with this invalid index will result in crash!

This bug seems to be fixed in the iOS8 GM seed, so it appears to be a beta problem only.

Comment: This post is very similar to what is going on but the iOS in question is 7.1.2. Thanks for the HIGHLY detailed information however. @Rob